# Stop animation before executing

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have made a slide by showing/hiding content depending on the option clicked. The problem is that when I click on more than one option very quickly the animations overlap themself, even crashing the functionality
Please check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/zhcoeaej/

And this is the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#lista ul li span").click(function(e) {
  var activo = "#" + $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

  if ($(activo).css("display") == "block") {
    return;
}

//Set list as inactive
$("#lista ul li span").each(function(index) {
  var clase = "." + $(this).attr("class");
  $("#lista ul li span").removeClass("activo");
});

//Hide all
$("#contenido > div").each(function(index) {
  var id = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
  $(id).hide("drop", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 600);
}).delay(600);

$(activo).show("drop", {
  direction: "right"
}, 600);
$(activo.replace("#", ".")).addClass("activo");
});
});
```

EDIT: I think I have not explained myself good, sorry. The code works fine but when I press option 1 and then option 2 and then option 3, one after the other, the content overlaps and there is a moment when you can see two contents visible

Comment: You can try to adding `.stop()` before `.hide()` havent tested it yet. This will stop other actions and starts the hide process. Otherwise try to put your animation within a `setTimeout(function(){ },timeInMilliseconds);`

Comment: @Blazemonger Can you convert your comment into an answer? Adding .finish() before hide() solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be able to solve this by using [`.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) to clear the animation queue before starting your animations again. However, something seems to be going wrong with the jQuery UI animations for `.hide()`. and `.show()`, and their animations are not finishing correctly when I add that method.

Instead, I tried replacing the jQueryUI `.hide()` and `.show()` with non-jQuery-UI `.animate()` that has the same result. This seems to work better, although things are somewhat complicated by the use of `.show()` and `.hide()` (which aren't animatable).

Additional CSS:

```
#contenido > div {
  position: relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#contenido > div").finish().not(activo).animate({
  left: '100%',
  opacity: 0,
}, 600, function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
clearTimeout(window.timer); // global variable
window.timer = setTimeout(function() {
  $(activo).show().animate({
    left: 0,
    opacity: 1
  }, 600);
  $(activo.replace("#", ".")).addClass("activo");
}, 600);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bzxtdywj/

Comment: The first time to run it has an erratic behaviour, the following times work perfect

Answer (score 0):

If i was you i would make two changes.

1) use absolute positions, so that if two boxes would accendently overlap it would do it as one is entering and the others is exiting, but in the correct position on the page.

2) use css3 transitions. That way you keep you code clean and readable. The only thing you would have do from the javascript is to add and remove classes. So a click action would be like this: `$("#element-clickable").click(function(){
$(".activo").each(function(){$(this).removeClass("show");}); // And now addClass "show" to the one you want to show.
})`

This way you make sure only to show one at the time.